# Бот для поиска по фото и словам

Tags: python, бот, telebot, photo

Помогите, пожалуйста, кто разбирается. У меня есть бот, написанный на pyTelegramBotAPI, но не могу в нём организовать одну функцию. Она заключается в том, что бот должен искать фото и видео по запросу пользователя. Например: юзер нажимает на кнопку фото, далее вводит ключевое слово или отправляет боту фото, похожее на то, которое он хочет найти и бот отправляет ему рандомное фото из интернета на эту тему. Аналогично и с видео. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Скорее всего поиск информации по фото, делается через ИИ.
https://habr.com/ru/post/678644/

Comment: Можешь из гугл запроса брать. Правда, одной функции для этого нет, придётся придумывать

Comment: теперь осталось придумать как из-под бота(и пайтон) делать запросі в гугл